# how to figure out the input data in nvd3.js Stacked Area Chart

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, stacked-area-chart

Guys I'm trying to implement a Stacked Area Chart using nvd3.js and angular.js the input data is as follows,

```
{ 
      "key" : "North America" , 
      "values" : [ [ 1025409600000 , 23.041422681023] , [ 1028088000000 , 19.854291255832],
       [ 1030766400000 , 21.02286281168], 
       [ 1033358400000 , 22.093608385173],
       [ 1036040400000 , 25.108079299458],
       [ 1038632400000 , 26.982389242348]]
}
```

I cant understand what this data represents. Specially the X axis data, It gets the date value from the data below but I cant figure it out. Any help would be great. The link to the original code is below
http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above data,

```
{ 
      "key" : "North America" , 
      "values" : [ [ 1025409600000 , 23.041422681023] , [ 1028088000000 , 19.854291255832],
       [ 1030766400000 , 21.02286281168], 
       [ 1033358400000 , 22.093608385173],
       [ 1036040400000 , 25.108079299458],
       [ 1038632400000 , 26.982389242348]]
}
```

> It shows one series of a stack bar chart. Where Key Indicates the
>   Series Name and The Values indicates the Stack, if you take the first
>   value **`1025409600000`** is the Date (Here its timestamp) and
>   **`19.854291255832`** is the y axis value. Similarly it goes on, You can have more series with different stacks.

You can see the [`FullStack`](http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedAreaData.json) Data here.